# BACKground image and back- color

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
</head>

<body style="background-color:lightblue;">

</body>
</html>
```

External css file:

```
body
  {


background-image:url("pass.jpeg"),url("skin.jfif");

  


    background-repeat: no-repeat,no-repeat;

    /* any background image will start from the top left corner of the element targeted*/

  background-size: 100% 50%, 100% 100%;

  /* setting the width and height of both the images */
  }
```

will the inline css over ride external css or external css will over ride ?
but i know that inline css specificity is higher.

Specifity does it even come here as both properties are different and element is same i.e body.

[image: OUTPUT]

Why the output is like this? what is going on?
How the whole process works?
Is the html parser first injects background color light blue to the whole body then embeds two back images.
Why the images are up there like a thin line

Answer (score 1):

well, there is a **hierarchy level on style, have always in mind that the closest style of the tag will be always the first** to take effect then the others will always be in the back of it.

As i can see, the problem in your code that are **making your images stretch is this line with: background-size: 100% 50%, 100% 100%; - The problem here is that you're using percentage as a metric**, you should use other metric numbers as px, em, rem, vw like width: 50px height: 50px;

You was trying to set up the width and height of the images right? I don't think you can set up it individually but only the width and height of the background. If you can cut or re-size the img on paint, then use it again. If you still want to re-size the background, i advice you to create a   inside your  tag, and try to put the images as background of this div, then use **background-size: 150px 100px;** for example, the background-size on this div.

Comment: thanks. I got it. I was saying why back image overwrites back color when i write content inside body ....or i give pixel value to back image .
what kind of specificity is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Inline styles (`style=""`) override internal stylesheets (`<style>`) which override external stylesheets (`<link>`). This is the **cascading** effect of CSS, which stands for **Cascading** StyleSheets. You can use `!important` after a style rule to give it more priority:

```css
body {
   background-image:url("pass.jpeg"),url("skin.jfif")!important;
   background-repeat: no-repeat,no-repeat;

    /* any background image will start from the top left corner of the element targeted*/

  background-size: 100% 50%, 100% 100%;

  /* setting the width and height of both the images */
}
```

Comment: if u see  carefully background image and background color both appears .
But back image appears as a fine line where back color appears in most section. why so ?
and if u write some text in between body tags then u will see that back image starts to increase .

Comment: i understood . i am using backi mage size as a percetage ..so it is 50 percent of body but there is no height of body

Comment: @SaumyojitDas Correct, but you should still follow what I said

Comment: back color always sits on the surface of the body right & on the top of the color sits the back image . What is the reason? Or this is a rule of CSS.

Why did SO moderators blocked me from asking new questions i dont know.